# When converting txt to docx using pandoc, how to specify default paragraph style?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert a txt file (markdown) to docx using pandoc with a special MS Word template. I'm doing it this way:

`pandoc -s --reference-docx=/path/to/my/template.dotx -o outfield.docx file.md`

The problem is that I have set up my template with a special "Body Paragraph" style, separate from the "Normal" style (because the various headings, etc. all are *based on* the "Normal" style. Is there a way to tell pandoc that when it converts normal paragraph text that it should be styled using my special "Body Paragraph" style?

Answer (score 5):

pandoc 1.19.2.1 uses three styles for body text: `Normal`, `Body Text`, and `First Paragraph`, which are based onto each other in this order. If you want a specific styling of your body text only, you should hence edit the `Body Text` style in the template, not the `Normal` style as changes to the `Normal` style -- as you already mentioned -- propagate to other styles as well.

See the part on the `--reference-docx` option in the ['Options Affecting Specific Writers' section](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options-affecting-specific-writers) of the pandoc user manual.

This feature might exist pre-1.19.2.1 version, I don't know when this has been introduced.

Answer (score 0):

**Also, you can convert batch (multiple) files with pandoc, if you use these lines:**

**.docx convert to .txt**

```
for i in *.docx ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.txt ; done
```

**.doc convert to .docx**

```
for i in *.doc ; do echo "$i" && pandoc -s --wrap=none $i -o $i.doc ; done
```